# hexadecimal to binary conversion

Tags: hex

I have a question:

1A45 (Hexadecimal) GB= ***_*____** (Binary) Bytes

Please tell how to fill in the answer!

Doing the calculation the conventional way, it takes a lot of time and i am not able to get the answer ...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

Comment: how are you doing the conversion?

Comment: Is this homework? Try to do it per hexadecimal digit. Since hexadecimal is base-16, and 16 is a power of 2, this is quite easy.

Comment: @mvds this ain't homework.. i am sitting for an interview..preparing for it.. i am doing like hexadecimal->decimal->binary and then also converting the GB to Bytes.. But this takes a long time.. any short way?

Comment: Yes, per hex digit, `1 = 0001, A = 1010, 4 = 0100, 5 = 0101`, then `GB = 1024^3`, and `1024=2^10`, so `GB=2^30`. Combining all: `0001 1010 0100 0101 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000` (leading 000 and spaces left there for clarity)

Comment: @mvds: thanks a lot! just 1 last stupid question: 2^30=1073741824 bytes... even if we convert this to binary we will be getting 1 somewhere... why then we only consider 30 zeros? :|

Comment: @user975234 a stupid question deserves a stupid answer ;-) How does one million times 5 (=5000000) not add a 1, while one million = 10^6 = 1000000? Why only add 6 zeroes and not the 1 somewhere? This is the exact same thing but then in base 10. In other words: Multiplying by `2^N` adds `N` zeroes in binary, just as multiplying by `10^N` adds `N` zeroes in decimal.

Comment: @user975234: ps. good luck with the interview!

Comment: This is elementary school maths, not computer science.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hex-Bin conversion is easy, because each hex digit is four bit long. Memorize this table, and you'll be able to do conversion in your head very easily:

```
0 0000
1 0001
2 0010
3 0011
4 0100
5 0101
6 0110
7 0111
8 1000
9 1001
A 1010
B 1011
C 1100
D 1101
E 1110
F 1111
```

Just replace each hex digit with its corresponding four bits, and you'll get the first part of your answer.

Now for the GB: K means 10 binary zeros, M means 20 binary zeros, G means 30 binary zeros. Add zeros to the end of your HEX-converted-to-BIN number to get your final answer.

Comment: @user975234 That's the part about K, M, and G. K is 1024, or 10 binary zeros; M is 1048576, or 20 binary zeros, and so on.

Comment: u mean the answer will be : 0001 1010 0100 0101 plus 30 binary zeros?

Comment: @mgibsonbr 10^9 is most common for hard drives (for marketing reasons); 2^30 is most common for everything else.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight true. Although the new GiB exists, it's seldom used. I agree with you, in this case it probably means 2^30.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: just 1 last stupid question: 2^30=1073741824 bytes... even if we convert this to binary we will be getting 1 somewhere... why then we only consider 30 zeros? :|

Comment: @user975234 It's the same thing that happens when you multiply by powers of ten in the decimal system: even through there's a 1 in front of zeros, you just add the zeros to the right of the number to get the answer. Two is the ten of the binary system, so the same technique applies there.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: It's not for marketing reasons.  It's because hard drive sizes are determined by physical dimensions and properties, not related to powers of 2.

Comment: @endolith Right, that's the rationalization. But the real driver behind it all was the desire to print 300 GB instead of 279 GB on the box. Ultimately this [cost WD a lot of money](http://betanews.com/2006/06/28/western-digital-settles-capacity-suit/) in a legal battle that they have lost.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Right, that's the silly conspiracy theory.  But the real truth is that manufacturers of hardware and media have been using normal metric prefixes [since the hardware was first invented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_binary_prefixes#cite_ref-45). They're engineers, not software guys.

Answer (score 1):

1A45 can be expressed in two 8 bit bytes as 00011010 01000101, the decimal value is 6725

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are two problems here:

1. Convert 1A45 from hex to binary (is it really binary you want?)
2. Multiply it for 10^9 or 2^30, depending on what definition of GB you're using.

The first is already answered by GoldenNewby, the second will depend on your needs.